# Getting row for NSButton in NSTable

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I am struggling with this one, can't help but feel i am missing something obvious!

I have an NSTable which contains a Table Cell View, which in turn contains an NSButton.

The button has an outlet defined, and the table view has an outlet defined.

I am using the following code to get the index of the row a button is in when the user clicks that button:

```
- (IBAction)approveButtonInTable:(id)sender {

    NSInteger selected = [self.tweetTableView clickedRow];
    NSLog(@"sender sends :%ld", selected);
}
```

However this always replied with a -1, which is not massively helpful.

Am i missing something very obvious here?

Thanks

Gareth

**Edit 1**

I have worked out that this does work if i use it on the outlet of the tableview, using this:

```
- (IBAction)tweetTableAction:(id)sender {
    NSInteger selected = [_tweetTableView clickedRow];
    NSLog(@"sender sends :%ld", selected);
}
```

However that doesn't really help me as i still can't get it to work when i click on the button, doh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say you're using an `NSTableCellView`, that tells me you're using a view-based table. In that case, you want to call `rowForView:`, passing in the button. I *believe* this method only works in the case (never tried it on a cell-based table).

```
- (IBAction)approveButtonInTable:(id)sender {
    NSInteger selected = [self.tweetTableView rowForView:sender];
    NSLog(@"sender sends :%ld", selected);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone looking a **Swift 3** version of Jablair answer.

Just implement @IBAction method.

```
@IBAction func approveButtonInTable(_ sender: Any) {
    let selectedRow = tweetTableView.row(for: sender as! NSView)
    print("sender sends \(selectedRow)")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the button is not the same as clicking the table row.  Your best bet is to populate the buttons with tags that relate to their position in the table (perhaps starting at 100), then use:

```
- (IBAction)approveButtonInTable:(id)sender {

    NSInteger selected = [sender tag] - 100;   // or whatever value you decide to start tagging
    NSLog(@"sender sends :%ld", selected);
}
```

Comment: As the buttons are generated by the tableview i assume i am going to have to override a class function to do this, do you have any pointers on specifically how to do this?

Comment: @GarethJeanne You'd have to do it in some method close to the end of init time.  Jablair's solution looks easier to implement.